# Can I retrieve macaddr8 column as a number?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgresql-10

I'm using PostgreSQL 10.

If I understand correctly, macaddr8 columns are internally stored as binary numbers.

When I retrieve data with my python/pandas/sqlachemy script, I get it as a string with column-separated hex bytes `'01:23:45:67:89:ab:cd:ef'`.

Is it possible to retrieve it as a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there is no function built-in for that, but you can do it with:

```sql
concat('x', replace(mac::text, ':', ''))::bit(64)::bigint
```

Example:

```sql
WITH values (mac) AS (VALUES ('01:23:45:67:89:ab:cd:ef'::macaddr8))
SELECT
    mac,
    concat('x', replace(mac::text, ':', ''))::bit(64)::bigint AS num
FROM values;
```

...results into:

```sql
           mac           |        num        
-------------------------+-------------------
 01:23:45:67:89:ab:cd:ef | 81985529216486895
(1 row)
```

Comment: Just put that into a function and you shouldn't mess up your queries too much. :-) I think you won't find a much better way than that up to PostgreSQL 11.

Comment: OK, fair enough. But as you've asked explicitly for a PostgreSQL version, please be so kind and mark an answer that solves the question successfully (although you're not going to use it) as solution.